# Edit on Express outputing JSON to database field

Tags: json, mongodb, express, controller

Trying to create my first simple CRUD in Express JS and I cant seem to find this annoying bug.

When I try to update a field, the JSON from that field, gets outputed to the view, instead of the new data.

Screenshot: http://i59.tinypic.com/wi5yj4.png

Controller gist: https://gist.github.com/tiansial/2ce28e3c9a25b251ff7c

Answer (score 0):

The `update` method is used for finding and updating documents without returning the documents that are updated. Basically what you're doing is finding documents without updating them, since the first parameter of the `update` function is the search criteria. You need to use the `save` function to update an exiting document, after updating it's properties.

Your code below, modified (not tested):

```
//PUT to update a blob by ID
.put(function(req, res) {
    //find the document by ID
    mongoose.model('Email').findById(req.id, function (err, email) {
        //add some logic to handle err
        if (email) {
            // Get our REST or form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
            email.email = req.body.email;
            email.password = req.body.password;
            email.servico = req.body.servico;

            //save the updated document
            email.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send("There was a problem updating the information to the database: " + err);
                } 
                else {
                    //HTML responds by going back to the page or you can be fancy and create a new view that shows a success page.
                    res.format({
                        html: function(){
                            res.redirect("/emails");
                        },
                        //JSON responds showing the updated values
                        json: function(){
                            res.json(email);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
```